# ios Simulator Could Not Find The Application To Simulate

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm having trouble with the iOS simulator. I'm currently on 10.7 and was using the simulator to test my website. During the testing, I switched the iOS version via the tool bar, and the application froze and quit. Upon restarting, I get the following error message, with a finder window, inviting me to choose an application:

"ios Simulator Could Not Find The Application To Simulate"

Here's what I've tried to fix the issue:

1: Attempt to identify the application it needs, but the only thing i could see to open was a printer app and the ios simulator app, which just results in a "only one iOS simulator can run at a time" error message.

2: Restart the Mac.

3: Download the new Xcode tools from the app store.

4: Restart again.

None of this has helped, and I'm really stuck without it at the moment. If anyone knows how to resolve the problem, I would be grateful to hear any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.

Open up a new shell, and shoot of this command: `sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` (assuming thats the location of the instal).

Then run the Xcode installer you got from the app store.

This removes all the plist files that were also installed with xcode, which aren't removed when you simply reinstall. This is as close as you can come to a complete xcode refresh without reinstalling your OS.

Comment: Cheers. Just back off holiday so sorry for the late 'thanks' but yeah,  it's all working now, but your method seems sound too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution that worked for me... the answer selected here did not.  I created a blank, "hello world" project and simply ran it.  When you run the app, it sends the app to the simulator and voila!  iOS Simulator has an app to simulate.  From that point forward, you should be able to open the iOS Simulator without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a while longer trying various things, it seems like I may have fixed it.

When asking for an application to open, I opened Xcode, and (weirdly) that opened up and left the testing shell visible, with the tool bar intact. I then selected the current version from the device options and hit the home button, and suddenly everything appeared.

Weird thing to have suddenly happened, but there you go.

I still can't test in iOS 3, so that's a bit of a problem, but not a disaster either!